# Sqlite: Find pairs of records that have common value

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables that look like this:

```
movie_cast
movie_id | cast_id | cast_name
10         2         Mark Hamill
10         3         Harrison Ford
10         4         Carrie Fisher
12         10        James Earl Jones
12         2         Mark Hamill
12         3         Harrison Ford
12         4         Carrie Fisher

movies
id   |   title
10       Star Wars IV
12       Star Wars V
```

I need to create a query that returns the pairs of actors who have been in at least 2 movies together.

So it should look something like this:

```
cast_member_id1 | cast_member_id2
2                 3
3                 4
```

I would normally put in my own query, but I have no idea where to start to get pairs in SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all the unique pairs of actors with a self join and some grouping, using `min()` and `max()` to get a canonical order. Then use a subquery with another self join to get the counts of the number of times the two share a movie:

```sql
WITH cast_pairs AS
  (SELECT min(a.cast_id,b.cast_id) AS cast_member_id1,
          max(a.cast_id,b.cast_id) AS cast_member_id2
   FROM movie_cast AS a
   JOIN movie_cast AS b ON a.cast_id <> b.cast_id
   GROUP by 1,2)
SELECT *
FROM cast_pairs
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
       FROM movie_cast AS m1
       JOIN movie_cast AS m2 ON m1.movie_id = m2.movie_id
       WHERE m1.cast_id = cast_member_id1 AND m2.cast_id = cast_member_id2) >= 2;
```

which gives

```
cast_member_id1  cast_member_id2
---------------  ---------------
2                3              
2                4              
3                4
```